# How to grep only the matching regex?

Tags: regex, grep, find, filenames

I write in a file **NotEmpty.txt** all my non-empty text files in a directory **dir** with the following command:

```
find dir/ -not -empty -ls | grep -E "*.txt" > NotEmpty.txt
```

I'd like to print only the matching regex and not all the information on the line. How is it possible?

Comment: So you want to print only things like 'dir/filename.txt' ?
Btw *.txt will match the whole line :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are executing `ls` against every match, so the output contains a lot of stuff. Instead, use this `find` command to print the name.

Note, in fact, that you can do everything in one shot, including selecting just `.txt` files:

```
find your_dir/ -not -empty -name "*.txt" -print > NotEmpty.txt
#                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^
#                                 |         |
#                          just .txt files  |
#                                           |
#                               print its name instead of `ls`ing it
```

You can also say `-type f` to just check files, which in fact I guess it is assumed by the `-not -empty` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-o` parameter of grep to specify that you only want the matching portion.

Example:

```
$ echo foo bar baz | grep -o "foo"
foo
```

Comment: The parameter `-o` doesn't work with the parameter -E (for regex).
Example :
`echo foo.txt bar.txt baz.txt | grep -oE "*.txt"` gives : 
`.txt
.txt
.txt`

I'm wondering how to make it possible with regex

Comment: @bam500 - It certainly does work with -E. It is likely that you're not getting the right result because your regex is malformed (`*.txt` is a glob expression, not a regular expression). You need to use `.*\.txt` for a regex.

Comment: Oh you're right! thank you for the little explanation. I need to read more about regex and how to use them!

Comment: @bam500 - You're welcome. Globs and regexes have a very similar syntax. It's very easy to mix them up!